# latex+dvips+ps2pdf vs. pdflatex

Tags: pdftex, pdf, ps2pdf

I have a problem with creating a pdf file. I hope I could get some clue from this community. I use mac tex.

method 1: pdflatex

pdf file is well created. The created file is not perfect. There occurs some
problem when I read it.

With acrobat reader, one of the page appears as blank. It seems that there is something wrong with the image in that page.

With skim, the page which the acrobat reader has read as blank page appears good. However, one of the images in that page does not show all the symbols in it. Some of the symbols appear as "fffff"

method 2: latex --> dvips --> ps2pdf

successfully create perfectly readable file.

What is the difference bewteen "latex+dvips+ps2pdf" and "pdflatex"?
Which ones better?
Thanks in advance.

--yj

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! Neither is better. Each has advantages and disadvantages. Generally, pdfLaTeX is more straightforward if it is an option but sometimes, you need to use the other route. The difference is just the engine: LaTeX produces DVI; pdfLaTeX produces PDF. In the one case, you are then turning DVI into postscript and postscript into PDF. If your file relies on postscript you *may* need to use this route or similar, though often nowadays this is no longer the case. Without an example of your code, it is hard to recommend one or the other. (Except: the one which works ;).)

Comment: As cfr hints, a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) would work great magic here :)